# How can a dictionary key be called without hardcoding references in the code like ie. if/else statements (with entry/input)?

Tags: python, python-3.6

```
d = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': '12345',
    'anotherKey': 'anotherValue',

}


for x in d.items():
    ans = input("Enter dict key")
    if ans in d:
        print("The key to {key} is {value}s".format(key=ans))
    if ans == ('key1'):
        print(d)
        
    else:
            print("It is not in the dictionary")
```

This example with a for loop is just an example. I have worked with  if/else statements and a working widget with entries but with a horrible code where every new variable had to be added in multiple places. It is therefore my goal now to grab keys in the dictionary from the input exclusively, not by hardcoding alternatives into the code. I am a bit amazed it is not more obvious for a beginner to get the input statement  to pick a key and present its value. If theres another way of handling the issue instead of dict, I am all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do `value=d[ans]` in the format string
Like this:

```
d = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': '12345',
    'anotherKey': 'anotherValue',

}


for x in d.items():
    ans = input("Enter dict key")
    if ans in d:
        print("The key to {key} is {value}s".format(key=ans, value=d[ans]))
        
    else:
        print("It is not in the dictionary")
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
>>> d={...}
>>> print(d.get('key_name'))
```

To get the value from key

Comment: Thx but I want to avoid the hardcoding of ´key name´. But I just got an idea. Maybe the input entry has to give the ´key_name` at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {
    'ebay': 'lösenord',
    'discogs': '12345',
    'banken': 'jättehemligt',
    'a': 'skithemligt',

}


for x in d.items():
    ans = input("Enter dict key")

    value=d[ans]

    print(d.get(ans))
```

Ps. I know working with passwords in this way is not recommended but that is another story :). Hashing and encryption coming up and that paper on the desk never before looked so appealing for passwords.

Comment: um, but if you input "apple" then it gives a keyerror KeyError: "apple"

Comment: How you'll fix that?